# Risk - To secure a world domination win?

Tags: risk

I have been playing Risk with my four best friends and i have very rarely won.

I have been wondering what is the best strategy to win at Risk?

Comment: http://boardgames.stackexchange.com/questions/113/what-are-some-good-tactics-for-the-early-game-in-risk

Comment: Do you ever secure Australia?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Usually securing a continent and ALWAYS being on the aggressive.

When you keep getting Territory cards and playing them at the right time (usually after your opponents have played them first so that the count will be higher), you should always have a formidable army (i.e. so that your opponents won't want to mess with you).

The other critical part to winning risk is being aggressive. You should be getting a territory card each turn usually in a quest to prevent your opponents from ever owning entire continents. This means you constantly annoy them by taking at least (and usually only) one territory of the continent they control on your turn. This prevents them from getting massive bonuses.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 3):

The cards are the the key

- always attack each turn to gain a card
- pay attention to how many cards everyone has.  You want to wipe out other players when they have cards you can then immediately turn in for additional sets and keep going
- do NOT attack other players if by doing so you'll just set them up for someone else to wipe out and get their cards.

Answer (score 2):

The key to Risk is "income" (in the form of armies).

Try to dominate a small continent early (most likely Australasia or South America, possibly Africa), so you get the extra "income" for a whole continent.

Make sure that you, or some "third" person maintains at least one territory on each continent, like a defensive stop in Monopoly so that no one else gets the income for a whole continent.

Except as related to the above, do not make too many attacks too early. Just make one attack each turn, get a card, and trade them for "income" as soon as possible.